# How to order records by associaction with has_many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, kaminari

I have two tables, authors and books, books have a publishing date, I would like to order authors by the date of their last published book, I was doing this `includes(:books).where(blablabla).order('books.published_date DESC')` but it breaks kaminari's pagination (8 records per page, 9 to be displayed), I get correct records on the first page, but on the second page I get first two records from the first page plus correct record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [Yap](https://github.com/1and1/yap). You can define an alias for `books.published_date` and sort by that alias. See the [example](https://github.com/1and1/yap#full-example).

```
User.joins(:team).paginate(sort: {team: :asc}) # would sort by team.name
```

Use `.includes(:team)` if you also need to access any attributes of it to use eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Author.includes(:books).where(blablabla).order('books.published_date DESC')
```

Update 1:-

```
@authors = Author.includes(:books).where(blablabla).order('books.published_date DESC')
@authors = @authors.page(params[:page)
```

Hope this may helpful!!

Comment: sorry missed the order part when copying from code editor

Comment: so that's exactly the query I'm doing, it works well but not with kaminari

Comment: with update 1, I get correct records for the first page, but for the second i get two first records from first page and then the last one (correct one)